# $(this).remove not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery

`$(this).remove()` works fine in all browsers but not working in Chrome. I am using this function to remove an image, it actually deletes that particular image div but chrome still displays that image. If I do minimize window and then maximize, chrome will not show that removed image.

EDIT: (taken from comments)

Html

```
<div class="image_holder"> <img src="img/someimage.png" /> </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".image_holder").live("click", function() { $(this).parent.remove(); });
```

Comment: Uhh... http://jsfiddle.net/vJygQ/

Comment: @ExplosionPills - I am already using this function and it is also working but chrome is not clearing the image held in cache, it still shown me that image as visible.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code you are using?

Comment: This is my HTML code holding image:

<div class="image_holder">
<img src="img/someimage.png" />
</div>

$(".image_holder").live("click", function() {
$(this).parent.remove();
});

This deletes the div, but still keep showing image

Comment: @ExplosionPills This is my HTML code holding image:

<div class="image_holder">
<img src="img/someimage.png" />
</div>

$(".image_holder").live("click", function() {
$(this).parent.remove();
});

This deletes the div, but still keep showing image

Comment: It should be `$(this).parent().remove()` not `$(this).parent.remove()`

Comment: @ExplosionPills I had also tried this with brackets but the thing is it deletes the div but not clearing the cache. it holds that image. function works perfect, i had also used parent(), but its not clearing the image cache in chrome.

Comment: You have no control over whether it clears the cache.  The image disappears for me in Chrome even if I remove the parent.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - I am using chrome 24.0.1312.52, what version are you usning? What do you suggest

Comment: if you are using jquery latest library i.e. `jquery v1.9`, they have deprecated `live()` from there list of api, use `delegate()` or `on()` instead, see [this link](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changes-of-note-in-jquery-1-9). otherwise i don't get why i did'nt work for you in chrome!

Comment: Have tried, still not successful. Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

this code works as i tested it [here](http://jsbin.com/iwozaz/2/edit) in chrome as well.

```
$(function()
 {
 $("div.image_holder").click(function()
 {
   $(this).remove();
   //or
   //$(this).hide();
 });
});
```

it did not give me any problem, its very basic approach, you were removing the `parent()` by clicking on parent itself. because image's parent is div in your case that contains the image.

Comment: did you checked the link i mentioned ??

Comment: Yes I checked. I am using the same function and code. But the cache from chrome is not going. The image gets deleted but it doesnt go away from chrome cache.

Comment: clear your browser cache then, use `ctrl+r` or `ctrl+f5` several times. its weird that its still in cache. besides i did not able to replicate what you are saying.